# Toad - error during copy to another schema "Where clauses are not configured for any tables."

Tags: toad

Within the Toad Database Schema Browser I am trying to copy data from one table to another under the option `Data -> Copy to another schema` but, under the `tables` tab, I don't know how to configure the where clause to specify which destination table I want for the data copy.

Toad Version 14.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `WHERE` clause is used to "copy" only those rows which satisfy the condition. You don't select tables here.

---

Answer to your problem is:

- destination schema should already have a target table (whose name and description are exactly the same as source table's). Or,
- simply check the **create destination tables if needed** checkbox in "Before copy" section and TOAD will create it for you